# my sql query keeps on fetching, is it the code or something else?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I try to connect three tables through the following code:

```
SELECT *
FROM tickets t
JOIN evenementen e
   ON e.idEvenement = t.fk_tiEvenementID
JOIN klanttyperesult k
   ON k.kltr_idKlant = t.fk_tiKlantID;
```

Is there a problem with code or should I look for the problem elsewhere?

Comment: how many rows are there?

Comment: Publish tickets table please

Comment: You should read JOINs of SQL first before attempting to write queries using JOIN. It can be complicated sometimes.

Comment: @AswaniMadhavan: 1606638 rows in tickets.

Comment: @nemja How long it takes?

Comment: @AswaniMadhavan I stopped it at 221 seconds

Comment: Did you defined indexes on the relavant fields?

Comment: EXPLAIN the select statement you're using : explain select * from ...etc.. you'll probably see the problem straight away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "keeps on fetching" I assume you mean hangs, chances are you're selecting a *lot* of data. To break down what your query is doing, and therefore why it would be taking a long time:

`SELECT *` - Select every single column from every table this query references. This will mean that you are returning a lot of data, if each table has 7 columns you'll be returning 21 columns worth of data.

`FROM tickets t` - From the table `tickets` with an alias of `t`

`JOIN evenementen e` - Join the table `evenementen` with alias `e`, filtering out results with no join condition between tables.

`ON e.idEvenement = t.fk_tiEvenementID` - On the condition given

`JOIN klanttyperesult k` - Join the table `klanttyperesult` with alias `k`, filtering out results with no join condition between tables.

`ON k.kltr_idKlant = t.fk_tiKlantID;` - On the condition given.

If these tables have lots of rows, then you're going to very quickly rack up into expensive join land.

You also might be lacking indexes, meaning you're using a nested-loop join (can be inefficient for large data sets, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/nested-loop-joins.html). Try adding some indexes to the tables like [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html).

`CREATE INDEX tickets_evenementenIdIdx ON tickets (fk_tiEvenementID)`

`CREATE INDEX tickets_klanttyperesultIdIdx ON tickets (fk_tiKlantID)`

`CREATE INDEX evenementen_ticketsIdIdx ON evenementen (idEvenement)`

`CREATE INDEX klanttyperesultIdIdx ON klanttyperesult (kltr_idKlant)`